# Storm 2.4.0 - Worker Heapsize Issue

Tags: memory, heap-memory, apache-storm, apache-storm-topology, apache-storm-configs

Although we have given the following parameters in Storm.yaml, it calculates the assigned total memory by multiplying the number of executors in the topology by onheap(128mb).

```
`topology.component.resources.onheap.memory.mb: 128.0
topology.component.resources.offheap.memory.mb: 0.0
topology.component.cpu.pcore.percent: 10.0
topology.worker.max.heap.size.mb: 768.0
worker.heap.memory.mb: 768`
```

Normally, when the heap is given to the worker on topology basis, it is divided by the number of executors in the topology. In Storm 2.4.0, I could not set this somehow.